# getting Failed to open browser: in GRPC with go tool setup

Tags: go, grpc-go

I did the go tool set up and try to run sample code it showed  Failed to open browser: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%. anyone can help

verified the environment path variable and folder structure also uninstall the go tool and tried still same issue

Comment: Did you refresh your terminal session to apply the environment variable(s)? Or if using linux you can do:
$ source ~/.bashrc  OR if using zsh: $ source ~/.zshrc

Comment: I was refresh my terminal and verified the env.variable path but still same issue. using windows 10. Is there any other suggestion ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: steps which I followed is 

1. Install go tool.
  https://go.dev/doc/install

2. change the environment variable.

3. Verified  the Go tool version by using the below command
   //go version

4. Then install the GRPC by using the below command:
 go install github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui/cmd/grpcui@latest

5. After installing use the below command:
  grpcui api.grpc.me:443 -- in this part it shows gRPC Web UI available at http://127.0.0.1:52461/
Failed to open browser: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%

Comment: got a solution for my case.  In system variable the below two path is missed so i was added the path and run it works fine 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\ and %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\